# Read char* as a single char (In C)

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I'm going to do my best to explain this, but if you can't quite understand what my problem is then feel free to ask for clarification :)

Working on a problem for a tutorial, where a plaintext message can be encrypted or a ciphertext message can be decrypted. Encrypting the plaintext message is working fine, what I'm stuck on is the decrypting. For the decrypting a series of numbers (each seperated by a space) are typed in and then decrypted back to the original characters. These series of numbers are saved in an unsigned char array named 'message'. Right now I am using the strtok method to split the 'message' string at each " ". I also know what my problem is, just not sure how to fix it. The encode function encrypts and decrypts and is working 100% fine. You'll notice in the code below that I pass in 109 to encode which outputs 'h' as it should. But, when I use the strtok method to get 109 from the message string, 109 isn't seen as a single number, instead it is seen as a 1, a 0, and a 9. Hopefully you're all still with me. Basically I want to know how I can have the 1, 0, and 9 seen as 1 single number? Thanks in advance

```
unsigned char *parts;
parts = strtok(message, " ");
int counter = 0;
printf("%c", encode(109, key, counter));
while (parts != NULL) {
  printf("%c", encode(*parts, key, counter));
  counter++;
  parts = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: The code here doesn't show the decode function.  How should we fix something we've never seen?

Comment: Additionally, in the tiny amount of code here, I _do_ see an error with the interaction between this code and the `encode` function.

Comment: The encode function is fine that's why I didn't post it. Just looking to represent an unsigned char array containing numbers, as a single unsigned char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `*parts` to the encode() function passes in the ASCII character '1'. You need to convert the char array to a single decimal value. Right now you have { '1', '0', '9', '\0' } and need 109. You can use something like `atoi( parts )`, so your call to encode is `encode( atoi( parts ), key, counter )`.

Answer (score 0):

try `strcat`

```
unsigned char *parts;
char fullnum[44];
strcpy(fullnum , "");
parts = strtok(message, " ");
int counter = 0;
printf("%c", encode(109, key, counter));
while (parts != NULL) {
  printf("%c", encode(*parts, key, counter));
  counter++;
  strcat(fullnum , part);
  parts = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

now `fullnum` will contain 109 as a string you can convert it to an int using `strtol`